# How to continue after except

Tags: python, try-catch, except

I have this script which converts hostnames to IP's. However when it finds one that does not exist, it stops. I would like it to continue even though there has been an exception, however I can't find my way.

```
#Script to resolve hostname to IP. Needs improving.
import socket

def file_len(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    return i + 1

def resolve_ip():

with open("test.txt", "r") as ins:
    try:
        for line in ins:
            print(socket.gethostbyname(line.strip()))

    except Exception:
            print(line)


resolve_ip()
```

Mainly, this prints all the IP's until there is an error. How can I continue after the exception converting the left lines?

Thank you

Comment: You haven't shown the outer loop that's driving this. Can you not just hoist `for line in ins:` out of the try/except?

Comment: Currently you have an all-or-nothing setup. Unless the file could actually be empty, `for line in ins:` doesn't look liable to fail, only `socket.gethostbyname(line.strip())` so it's not clear why you have the loop inside the `try` block unless I'm misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

```
#Script to resolve hostname to IP. Needs improving.
import socket

def resolve_ip(file_name):
    with open(file_name, "r") as ins:
        for line in ins:
            line = line.strip()
            try:
                print(socket.gethostbyname(line))
            except socket.gaierror:
                print(line)

resolve_ip('test.txt')
```

Note that your other function would raise an exception if the file is empty. Also you don't need to iterate over the file. use `readlines()` method of file object to read all lines in a list then just return `len` of this list.

Comment: Iterating over the file is generally better than `readlines()` because it does not load the whole contents into memory at once. Using `range(len())`, which I think is what you are suggesting, would be much less Pythonic.

Comment: @roganjosh I agree iterating over file is better tha reading it in the memory. I was suggesting `readlines()` given OP goal to get the number of lines. If they iterate they need to account for the possibility of empty file and amend their code accordingly. I did NOT suggest `range(len())`